# Long running Cronjob php script stops without error

Tags: php, cron, timeout

first i know this looks like a duplicate, but i tried a lot of things suggested in asked in nearly identical questions.

I have a website which i dont host on my own, but by a hoster. I need to update my data regulary. My aproach is to let a cronjob call a php on my webspace which then updates the data which takes around 5-6 minutes at the moment.

When i open the php myself in my browser in works completely fine. (of course blank for the processing time, but it runs fully and updates all data.)
But when i let the cronjob do it (via cron-job.org) it stops after around 2 min 30 seconds without any error given. (i log the process via echo and logging to a file)

I dont have direct access to the php.ini to modify the variables in there so i tried the following:
ignore_user_abort(true);

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('max_execution_time','600'); 
ini_set('max_input_time','600');
```

I know that cron-job.org timeouts after 30 seconds, but i understodd it so that ignore user abort solves that part.

Im absolutely clueless what to do do make this work and i dont see an other way to automate my update process.

Thanks in advance

edit: i dont want to update anything in a database so "update first 100 rows" doesnt really work for me.. im updatign a json.

Comment: you could maybe break your script to import a small amout of data per time (E.g.: import first 100 rows... them another 100 and so on.

Comment: problem is i dont update anything in my database, im updateing data in a jposn which i load, manipulate over the process time and write back

Comment: Its a very limited environment, I can only imagine some kind of job queue that you could create with database or even a txt file, then skip that records on next process.

You only have to find a way to unique identify the data, so you know that you must skip.